# unable to register new user from ejabbered xmpp in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xmpp, ejabberd

In SignupViewController

```
if (![[[self appdelegate] xmppStream] isConnected]) {
            [[self appdelegate] setupStream];
            [[self appdelegate]connect] && [[self appdelegate].xmppStream supportsInBandRegistration];

        } else {
            [[self  appdelegate] registerWithElements];
        }
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)registerWithElements {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:[UserDefaultsManager getUsername]]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:[UserDefaultsManager getPassword]]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"email" stringValue:[UserDefaultsManager getUsername]]];

    [[self xmppStream] registerWithElements:elements error:&error];
}
```

It always goes in didNotRegister method. Please provide a suitable solution to register successfully.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you :

```
- (AppDelegate *)appDelegate
{
    return (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
}

- (XMPPStream *)xmppStream {
    return [[self appDelegate] xmppStream];
}

-(void)registerUser {
    NSString *myJID = userName;
    NSString *myPassword = password;

    //
    // If you don't want to use the Settings view to set the JID,
    // uncomment the section below to hard code a JID and password.
    //
    //   myJID = @"raj@h.local";
    //   myPassword = @"123";

    //if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
    //    return ;
    //}

    [_xmppStreamM setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
    //password = myPassword;

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![_xmppStreamM connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
        if (myJID == nil || myPassword == nil) {
            return ;;
        }

    [_xmppStreamM setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];
    //_password = myPassword;

    //NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_xmppStreamM connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:&error])
        [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] connectWithTimeout:XMPPStreamTimeoutNone error:nil];

    //_userName = self.userName.text;
    //  NSString *password = self.password.text;
    //    NSString *name =@"raj";
    //
    //
    //    NSString *email=@"raj@gmail.com";


    NSMutableArray *elements = [NSMutableArray array];

    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"username" stringValue:@"username"]];
    [elements addObject:[NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"password" stringValue:@"password"]];

    [[[self appDelegate] xmppStream] registerWithElements:elements error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Register ====%@",[[self appDelegate] xmppStream]);
    NSLog(@"Register ====%@",elements);
}
```

Comment: No. I already did the same thing above by calling that from app delegate. So Can you plz explain why i need to write this.

Comment: I am always facing this issue 
 ERROR :- <iq xmlns="jabber:client" from="bhuvan-mac-2.local" type="error"><query xmlns="jabber:iq:register"><username>sdg@bhuvan-mac-2.local</username><password>sdgdsg</password><email>sdg@bhuvan-mac-2.local</email></query><error code="400" type="modify"><bad-request xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"/></error></iq>

Comment: @Bhu which part you didn't understand?

Comment: I have registered successfully and through breakpoint already verified that registerWithElements is returns YES , my main concern is the error I faced. Bad request error.

Comment: @Bhu.ONEBhatt have you checked at your server whether the user is registered or not?

Comment: No it is not. I have to registered manually through the app and in that I am not able to do that. Can you provide me simple steps to reach up to registration. It will really help me if you can do so.

Comment: @Bhu.ONEBhatt have you tried my code? and for reference you can follow this https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/WorkingWithElements

Comment: Yes @sushrita but nothing happened ...... Let just suppose I have a method  -(void)registeruser.... what I need to write excpet your code.

Comment: @Bhu.ONEBhatt     
    NSString *myJID = self.userName.text;
    NSString *myPassword = self.password.text;
[_xmppStreamM setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:myJID]];

Comment: actually the answer is too long for writing it in the comment box.

Comment: Yeah I know thats why I am not able to ask you :P

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can provide me any demoProject link.

Comment: @Bhu.ONEBhatt which server are you using openfire or anything else? you can refer to this link http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-server-setup--mobile-6958

Comment: I followed this link but their is nothing about how to register in this link..... and I am using ejabbered server